# How would I find the next free element in a string array in C++ then append data to it?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Exzample code...

```
const int SIZEOFFILENAMES = 100;
string fileNames[SIZEOFFILENAMES];


int main () {


    string inFilePath;
    cout << "Specify the file path:" << endl;
    cin >> inFilePath;  

    ifstream inFile;
    // open in binary
    inFile.open(inFilePath.c_str(), ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
    int fileLen = inFile.tellg();
    inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

        char charArr[10000];
    inFile.read(charArr, fileLen);
    inFile.close();
    inFile.clear(ios_base::goodbit);
```

Pesudo code would be.

1. Check filename Array element size.
2. append inFilePath to Next Free element.

}

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: would you be kind enough to offer a example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BrianDanielPemberton - did google refuse your request already? Try here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ (Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow. Hope you enjoy your stay)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial minimal example for adding the inputted filepath to your vector of filenames:

```
// ...
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::vector<std::string> fileNames;


int main ()
{
  std::string inFilePath;
  std::cout << "Specify the file path:" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> inFilePath;

  filenames.push_back(inFilePath);
  // do other stuff
  // ...
}
```